# How to scrape a user review when each review has separate div id?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, xpath, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape reviews from [team-bhp.com](https://www.team-bhp.com/). However, I noticed that each user review has a separate **div id**

1. **xpath** is of form: `//*[@id="post_message_4655182"]`
2. **html** is of form: `<div id="post_message_4655182">`
   I'm open to using any library like bs4 or lxml, but I prefer python. My code:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

url = 'https://www.team-bhp.com/forum/luxury-imports-niche/213083-looking-buying-bmw-x1-need-advice.html'

path = '///*[@id="post_message_4657893"]'
response = requests.get(url)
byte_data = response.content
source_code = html.fromstring(byte_data)

tree = source_code.xpath(path) 

print(tree[0].text_content())
```

This gives the proper output like:
*Hi Hajaar,
We recently closed a deal for a BMW X1. Here are a few things I would like to share:
Bargain hard...*
But here I have hard coded the specific comment id. How to extract all reviews from a single page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjust your `XPATH` and use `starts-with()` to get your goal:

```
path = '//*[starts-with(@id,"post_message_")]'
```

##### Example

```
import requests    
from lxml import html

url = 'https://www.team-bhp.com/forum/luxury-imports-niche/213083-looking-buying-bmw-x1-need-advice.html'

path = '//*[starts-with(@id,"post_message_")]'
source_code = html.fromstring(requests.get(url).content)

for e in source_code.xpath(path):
    print(e.text_content())
```

Or while tagged with `BeautifulSoup`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.team-bhp.com/forum/luxury-imports-niche/213083-looking-buying-bmw-x1-need-advice.html'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content)

for e in soup.select('[id^="post_message_"]'):
    print(e.get_text())
```